# How to count order item by order status?

Tags: magento2

> If in order #1 is product "a" with qty = 10 [ status: complete ] and product "b" with qty 2 [ status: closed ],
>   order #2 is product "a" with qty = 13 [ status: complete ] and product "b" with qty 3 [ status: closed ]
>   => count order by status = 23 [ status: complete ]
>   or
>   => count order by status = 5 [ status: closed]

My config:

```
public function toOptionArray()
{
    $options = $this->statusCollectionFactory->create()->toOptionArray();
    return $options;
}
```

[image]

My controller:

```
$orderItems = $this->orderItemCollection->create();
        $orderItems->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $sku);
        $orderItems->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
        $orderItems->getSelect()->columns(array('count' => 'SUM(qty_ordered)'));
        $countOrders = $orderItems->getFirstItem()->getData('count');
        $availableQty = $qty - $countOrders;
```